# Objective-C: Why is my if statement not working?

Tags: objective-c, uiswitch

Here i have some code that checks if the iphone has a camera flash. And then check if my switch is on by using this code:

```
 if(switch1.on){

                }
```

The light turns on fine without this code and i have also tried this code as well:

```
if(!(switch1.on)){

                  }
```

and that successfully turns my camera flash on but also turns it on even when the switch is set to off

Here is my full code:

```
-(IBAction)torchon:(id)sender{
    AVCaptureDevice *flashlight = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if ([flashlight isTorchAvailable] & [flashlight isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn]) {

        BOOL success = [flashlight lockForConfiguration:Nil];
        if(success){
            if(switch1.on){ //// or (!(switch1.on))

                on.hidden = YES;
                [UIScreen mainScreen].brightness = 1.0;
                [flashlight setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
                [flashlight unlockForConfiguration];
            }
       }
    }    
}
```

any help would be appreciated

```
**EDIT:**
```

Here is the code where i set the switch to no using ibactions when the value of the switch has changed. This code works successfully:

```
-(IBAction)switch1{
    if (switch1.on) {
        switch1.on = YES;
        switch2.on = NO;
    } else{
        switch2.on = YES;
        switch1.on  = NO;
    }    
}

-(IBAction)switch2{
    if (switch2.on) {
        switch2.on = YES;
        switch1.on  = NO;
    } else{
        switch1.on = YES;
        switch2.on = NO;
    }
}
```

**Answer**

First add a bool:

```
bool yes;
```

then set that bool in the `viewdidload`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    yes = YES;
}
```

After that set it to YES when the ibaction is called and set it to NO once the switch is turned off:

```
-(IBAction)switch1{
    if (swich1.on) {
    swich1.on = YES;
    swich2.on = NO;
        yes = YES;
    }

}


-(IBAction)switch2{
    if (swich2.on) {

    swich2.on = YES;
    swich1.on  = NO;
        yes = NO;
    }

}
```

lastly where it checks `if(switch1.on){}` you need to change it to `if(yes==YES){}` so together that if statement looks like this:

```
-(IBAction)torchon:(id)sender{
    AVCaptureDevice *flashlight = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if ([flashlight isTorchAvailable] & [flashlight isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn]) {

        BOOL success = [flashlight lockForConfiguration:Nil];
        if(success){
            if(yes==YES){
                on.hidden = YES;
                [UIScreen mainScreen].brightness = 1.0;
                [flashlight setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
                [flashlight unlockForConfiguration];

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Not an Xcode question. Any chances `switch1` is `nil`?

Comment: can we see the code where you set `on=NO`?

Comment: @Anoop Vaidya Sure check my edit!

Comment: What are you trying to do? if it is YES you are making it YES, and if it is NO you are making it NO.. plz check again

Comment: The first thing you should do: Set breakpoints in the debugger and check what your code does. That should reveal the problem quickly.

Comment: @Anoop Vaidya I have checked through all yes and no's for the switch are set correctly and are sated where they are meant to be so that is not the problem.

Comment: Anoop is right: `if (switch1.on) { switch1.on = YES; ... }` does not make any sense.

Comment: @user2534692 I would advise you to start using more descriptive and distinguishable names for your variables. It will lead to better productivity and compatibility with colleagues.

Comment: `yes = NO;` that is kind of funny…

Answer (score 0):

The `UISwitch` has another getter for the `on` property.

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isOn) BOOL on;
```

It may be better to use `.isOn` instead of `.on` for getting the value.

Also, some of your code can be simplified:

```
-(IBAction)switch1{
    [switch2 setOn:!switch1.isOn];    
}

-(IBAction)switch2{
    [switch1 setOn:!switch2.isOn];
}
```

It can get even better if you use the `sender` of the action in your methods.

Comment: I don't think that it makes any difference if you check `switch.on` or `switch.isOn`.

Comment: @MartinR It doesn't. It's just good practice. As for the particular problem, some more info is needed.

Comment: I have posted the answer on how to successfully fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `IBAction` methods have a similar form as the getter for the switch. It is possible that this could lead to undesired side effects. Refactor your methods to a single method, more in line with good programming practice:

```
-(IBAction)switchDidChange:(UISwitch*)aSwitch {
   UISwitch* otherSwitch = (aSwitch == switch1)? switch2 : switch1;
   [otherSwitch setOn:!aSwitch.on animated:YES];
}
```

Also, in your code the `on` property does not really seem to influence what is switched on or off. Include this conditionality.

Comment: `switch` is a C keyword and can not be used as variable name!